# Delphi: Reading number of columns + names from dataset?

Tags: delphi, dataset

Since Embarcadero's NNTP server stopped responding since yesterday, I figured I could ask here: I work with a non-DB-aware grid, and I need to loop through a dataset to extract the number of columns, their name, the number of rows and the value of each fields in each row.

I know to read the values for all the fields in each row, but I don't know how to extract column-related information. Does someone have some code handy?

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  index : Integer;
begin
  With ASQLite3DB1 do begin
      DefaultDir := ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName);
      Database := 'test.sqlite';
      CharacterEncoding := 'STANDARD';
      Open;
  end;

  With ASQLite3Query1 do begin
    ASQLite3Query1.Connection := ASQLite3DB1;

    SQL.Text := 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, label VARCHAR)';
    ExecSQL;

    SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO mytable (label) VALUES ("dummy label")';
    ExecSQL;

    SQL.Text := 'SELECT id AS Identification, label AS Label FROM mytable';
    Open;

    //How to get column numbers + names to initialized grid object?
    for index := 0 to ASQLite3Query1. - 1 do begin

    end;

    for index := 0 to FieldCount - 1 do begin
      ShowMessage(Fields[index].AsString);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number of fields and their names could be acquired as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Query1 do
  begin
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(FieldCount));
    ShowMessage(Fields[0].FieldName);
  end;
end;
```

You can checkout `TFieldDef` for more detail info about the field.

`dataset.FieldDefs[0]` has properties like `DataType` and `Size`.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're looking for is a list of field names, try creating a TStringList and passing it to the TDataset.Fields.GetFieldNames procedure.

If you want more information about fields, the TFields object (ASQLite3Query1.Fields) has a **default** property and a Count property, so you can use it like an array, and an enumerator, both of which can be used to loop over each TField object and retrieve its metadata.

Comment: Mason, I did edit the question by improving the code formatting, I didn't change the "handy?.", but I saw your name with code formatting revision which I did and mine with "handy?", seems it's concurrency problem with SO :-)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I fixed the code formatting, and didn't touch anything else in the post, the first time.  Later on, after I noticed the ?. thing, I fixed that too, but that was long afterwards.

Comment: I mean, I didn't made the changes in revision marked with my name, I did the same code regarding the code formatting (removed [code] tags), but I saw it marked with your name, so I thought it was concurrency problem with SO.